# How to Host SVC file in win form apps WCF

Tags: wcf

i am new in WCF. i know how to host wcf service in windows form. now i develop a small wcf service which has .svc file. i want to host this svc file in win form. so just want to know process will be same or different?

here is my svc file markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
Service="Services.ChatService" CodeBehind="ChatService.svc.cs" %>
```

here is small code inside svc file code behind file

```
namespace Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements the chat service interface.
    /// </summary>
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, 
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class ChatService : IChatService
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Guid, IChatServiceCallback> clients = 
            new Dictionary<Guid, IChatServiceCallback>();

        #region IChatService

        Guid IChatService.Subscribe()
        {
            IChatServiceCallback callback =
                OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IChatServiceCallback>();

            Guid clientId = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (callback != null)
            {
                lock (clients)
                {
                    clients.Add(clientId, callback);
                }
            }

            return clientId;
        }

        void IChatService.Unsubscribe(Guid clientId)
        {
            lock (clients)
            {
                if (clients.ContainsKey(clientId))
                {
                    clients.Remove(clientId);
                }
            }
        }

        void IChatService.KeepConnection()
        {
            // Do nothing.
        }

        void IChatService.SendMessage(Guid clientId, string message)
        {
            BroadcastMessage(clientId, message);
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies the clients of messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">Identifies the client that sent the message.</param>
        /// <param name="message">The message to be sent to all connected clients.</param>
        private void BroadcastMessage(Guid clientId, string message)
        {
            // Call each client's callback method
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
            (
                delegate
                {
                    lock (clients)
                    {
                        List<Guid> disconnectedClientGuids = new List<Guid>();

                        foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, IChatServiceCallback> client in clients)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                client.Value.HandleMessage(message);
                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                // TODO: Better to catch specific exception types.                     

                                // If a timeout exception occurred, it means that the server
                                // can't connect to the client. It might be because of a network
                                // error, or the client was closed  prematurely due to an exception or
                                // and was unable to unregister from the server. In any case, we 
                                // must remove the client from the list of clients.

                                // Another type of exception that might occur is that the communication
                                // object is aborted, or is closed.

                                // Mark the key for deletion. We will delete the client after the 
                                // for-loop because using foreach construct makes the clients collection
                                // non-modifiable while in the loop.
                                disconnectedClientGuids.Add(client.Key);
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (Guid clientGuid in disconnectedClientGuids)
                        {
                            clients.Remove(clientGuid);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

here is binding info

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Services.ChatServiceBehavior" name="Services.ChatService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChatService" contract="Services.IChatService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
```

**here is two endpoint one for wsDualHttpBinding and another one for mex**
so now my mex endpoint is

```
http://localhost:49722/ChatService.svc?wsdl
```

now i want to add another tcp endpoint and expose this service with two endpoint. so just tell me what i need to write for tcp endpoint and when i add tcp endpoint then what will mex endpoint for tcp because i want that user can create proxy with any of two url
one would be http url and another would be tcp url. so do i need to add mex for tcp here?

please guide me. thanks

Comment: i search lot google for getting info how to host svc file in win apps but found none for svc file example. why i am working with svc file because svc file can be hosted in IIS. if i can host it in win apps then i can add tcp endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must start host manually

follow to msdn link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx

---

edited

```
ServiceHost _serviceHost;
public void Start(Type type)
{
    _serviceHost = new ServiceHost(type);
    _serviceHost.Open();
}
```

Comment: i am not working with wcf service library rather i am working on wcf service application where svc file is generated. u gave me the link for hosting wcf service library dll in win or console apps. i know how to host svc file in IIS but i want to know how to host svc file with the help of ServiceHost class in win apps. the link u gave i think it is for those people who work with wcf service library rather wcf service apps template. it will be great help if u give me the right article link. thanks

Comment: can't to host svc file with the help of ServiceHost class by default way, you can write own class for you purpose

Comment: write deserializator for svc file, you will have calss with fields: Language, Debug, Service, CodeBehind. Get type from Service by reflection and use added code in my answer

Comment: u said...write deserializator for svc file. can u please give me some code which will work as deserializator for svc file. i really do not understand they way u guide me because i am very new in WCF. thanks

Comment: parse by regex and fill class, f.e. Regex.Match(sourseSrting, @"(?<=Service=")(.+?)(?=")") return service